# A phrase to mean "if that point is solved, the rest of the problem will be solved"

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a phrase that is in the same spirit such as "single point of failure", or "bottleneck". Example:

> Being two engineers short is <-term goes here-> in this situation. If we
>   find two engineers, the project will meet the deadline.

Another one:

> Electric cars are improved enough to be on par with internal
>   combustion engine cars. However, the long charging time is <-term goes
>   here-> behind the problem that electric cars are not as widespread as
>   internal combustion engine cars.

Comment: The ***root cause*** (which is prevalent in IT ops jargon).

Comment: The sense of both your examples suggests 'limiting'.

Comment: "critical point", "crucial issue" or "key issue".

Answer (score 2):

***crux***, [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/45327?redirectedFrom=crux#eid)

> The chief problem; the central or decisive point of interest.
>
> Example: 1934   R. Benedict Patterns of Culture vii. 232   The crux of
>   the matter is that the behaviour under consideration must pass through
>   the needle's eye of social acceptance.

The OP's two examples would then be slightly rewritten to read:

> Being two engineers short is the crux of our problem. If we find two
>   engineers, the project will meet the deadline.
>
> Electric cars are improved enough to be on par with internal
>   combustion engine cars. However, the long charging time is the crux of the
>   problem causing the slow inroads electric cars are making on internal
>   combustion engine cars.

In rock climbing, the crux is, according to Wikipedia, [Glossary of Climbing Terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_climbing_terms)

> The most difficult portion of a climb

Answer (score 0):

There are several terms from project management that might work, but they aren't single words.

[**Critical success factor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_success_factor): an element that is necessary for an organization or project to achieve its mission.

[**Long pole in the tent**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68616/alternative-to-saying-long-pole-in-the-tent): the issue preventing forward progress on a project.  This is more of a slang term, link goes to previous SE question about alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for ***Achilles' heel***.

M-W:

> **[Achilles' heel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Achilles'%20heel)**
>   *noun*
>
> : a fault or weakness that causes or could cause someone or something
>   to fail
>
> I'm trying to lose weight, but ice cream is my Achilles' heel.
>
> the food supply proved to be the nation's Achilles' heel in its
>   defense against terrorist attacks

Answer (score 0):

How about *roadblock*?

From Merriam-Webster:

> [roadblock](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roadblock): something
>   that blocks progress or prevents accomplishment of an objective

The OP's examples:

> Being two engineers short is a *roadblock* in this situation. If we
>   find two engineers, the project will meet the deadline. Another one:
>
> Electric cars are improved enough to be on par with internal
>   combustion engine cars. However, the long charging time is a
>   *roadblock* behind the problem that electric cars are not as widespread as internal combustion engine cars.

A *roadblock* is a barrier to progress. Once a *roadblock* is removed, the road is clear -- progress can proceed unimpeded.

Answer (score 0):

*critical factor*

or

*key*

Somewhat helpful definitions I found:

> *critical*: of decisive importance with respect to the outcome; crucial:
>   a critical moment.  (dictionary.com)
>
> *key* (adj.): chief; major; important; essential; fundamental; pivotal:
>   a key person in the company; key industries.  (dictionary.com)

Examples:

> Having enough staffing will be the *critical factor* in meeting the deadline.
>
> Having enough staffing is *key* to meeting the deadline.
>
> The long charging time is the *key reason* electric cars are not as widespread as internal combustion engine cars.  (or the critical reason)